# Exposing a TCP port out of cluster in Kubernetes using nginx-Ingress

Tags: nginx, tcp, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

So I have setup my application on Google cloud using Kubernetes. I have a Pod which I want to expose out of the cluster that expects TCP requests.

I came to know that this is possible via [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) and researched about it. As mentioned in the [docs here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/nginx-0.9.0/docs/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services.md), it can be done by setting up a configMap like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-configmap-example
data:
  9000: "default/my-service-name:7051
```

, but it's full usage is not clearly described nor I could find a complete example in the docs properly.

I have installed ingress-nginx as mentioned in the [Installation Guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) but I am unsure what the next steps are to expose my Pod.

**Extra Info**

- The port in the Pod that I want to expose out of cluster is `7051`
- I have a NodePort Service that targets my Pod's port that can be used with Ingress to expose.

Answer (score 6):

So, in order to achieve this you can do this:

1. First create the configMap that you added to the post.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-configmap-example
data:
  9000: "default/my-service-name:7051
```

2. Then edit your nginx-ingress-controller deployment by adding this flag to container args like below:

   ```
   ...
   containers:
   - name: nginx-ingress-controller
     image: "quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.26.1"
     imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
     args:
       - /nginx-ingress-controller
       - --default-backend-service=nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-default-backend
       - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
       - --ingress-class=nginx
       - --configmap=nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-controller
       - --tcp-services-configmap=default/tcp-configmap-example
       ...
   ```
3. Edit LoadBalancer service by adding port to your LoadBalancer

   ```
   ...
   ports:
   - name: http
     port: 80
     protocol: TCP
     targetPort: http
   - name: https
     port: 443
     protocol: TCP
     targetPort: https
   - name: some-service-port
     port: 7051
     protocol: TCP
   ```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How do I find the nginx-ingress-controller deployment?  Looking through kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces did not turn up any such deployment for me.  Is it possible it doesn't exist in some setups (using microk8s, here).

Comment: You need to install nginx ingress controller to you k8s cluster first. It doesn't come out of box generally.

Comment: I added nginx ingress through the microk8s command, but was confused, because it has controllerrevisions and a daemonset in the ingress namespace and doesn't seem to have a deployment in any namespace.  Evidently, I had to edit the daemonset (which creates the controllerrevisions), and the daemonset defines pod creation instead of a deployment.

Comment: I have never used microk8s unfortunately, but still just delete ingress namespace. 
And I recommend to install nginx-ingress thgrough helm https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm.

If you don't have helm installed, to install helm check `From script` part from https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/

Comment: I am confused at which port needs to be put where in 9000: "default/my-service-name:7051.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing with `helm` there is a way to expose tcp ports by setting values.

```sh
# add helm repo
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update
```

`helm show values ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx` will show the `values.yaml` file for reference, there are two dictionaries for exposing ports: `tcp` and `udp`:

```yaml
# TCP service key:value pairs
# Ref: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services.md
##
tcp: {}
#  8080: "default/example-tcp-svc:9000"

# UDP service key:value pairs
# Ref: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services.md
##
udp: {}
#  53: "kube-system/kube-dns:53"
```

To set the values from command line:

```sh
# set `tcp` dictionary in values (other `helm install` options omitted, only left options regarding to exposing tcp ports)
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --set tcp.12345=some-namespace/some-service:80
```