# How to access postgresql, deployed on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, deployment

I have deployed postgresql pod on kubernetes pod, and want to know how can I access postgresql gui. I am not able to access it with ingress path, as I got to know ingress are meant for https purpose only whereas postgres follows TCP protocol. Any lead how can I access through GUI?

deployment.yaml

```
---
  apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  kind: "Deployment"
  metadata: 
    name: "postgresql-development"
    namespace: "development"
  spec: 
    selector: 
      matchLabels: 
        app: "postgresql-development"
    replicas: 1
    strategy: 
      type: "RollingUpdate"
      rollingUpdate: 
        maxSurge: 1
        maxUnavailable: 1
    minReadySeconds: 5
    template: 
      metadata: 
        labels: 
          app: "postgresql-development"
          tier: "mysql"
      spec: 
        containers: 
          - 
            name: "postgresql-development"
            image: "postgresql:12.6"
            imagePullPolicy: "Always"
            env: 
              - 
                name: "POSTGRES_USER"
                value: "postgres"
            ports: 
              - 
                containerPort: 5432
                name: "postgres"
                
            volumeMounts: 
              - 
                name: "postgresql-persistent-storage"
                mountPath: "/var/lib/postgresql"
                
        volumes: 
          - 
            name: "postgresql-persistent-storage"
            persistentVolumeClaim: 
              claimName: "postgresql-pvc-development"


                
        imagePullSecrets: 
          - 
            name: "postgresql"
```

service.yaml

```
---
  apiVersion: "v1"
  kind: "Service"
  metadata: 
    name: "postgresql-development"
    namespace: "development"
    labels: 
      app: "postgresql-development"
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  spec: 
    ports: 
      - 
        port: 59799
        targetPort: 5432
        protocol: TCP
    selector: 
      app: "postgresql-development"
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
      tier: mysql
```

ingress.yaml

```
---
  apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"
  kind: "Ingress"
  metadata: 
    name: "postgresql-development-ingress"
    namespace: "development"
    annotations: 
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
  spec: 
    rules: 
      - 
        host: "localhost"
        http: 
          paths: 
            - 
              backend: 
                serviceName: "postgresql-development"
                servicePort: 59799
              path: "postgresql-development/(.*)"
```

Comment: You will want to read up on `NodePort`, or it may also be possible to use the `tcp` port exposure of nginx-ingress, if you're using that one. Depending on how permanent this need is, `kubectl port-forward` also works great. Separately, you will also want to exercise **extreme caution** trying to use `Deployment` for something that is actually a `StatefulSet`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ingress API are only for Layer 7 (HTTP). In your case you want to access Layer 4 (TCP).

To achieve you goal, you can:

- Use a [Nodeport](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) on your service
- A Ingress Controller that handle TCP like [Traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/#kind-ingressroutetcp) or [Nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/)
- for local development, [Port Forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)

Comment: the far more common nginx ingress controller [also supports TCP and UDP](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/), if you wish to include that in your answer

Comment: Yes, but not as easy as Traefik

Comment: I have updated the service.yaml file in my question can you please check if it's correct. Also wanted to know what would be the url to access the GUI?

Comment: If you use nginx, you also need to create a configmap with the right mapping. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53060092/exposing-a-tcp-port-out-of-cluster-in-kubernetes-using-nginx-ingress